# dynamically create elements in Polymer and setting attributes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Considering defining a polymer element

```
<dom-module id="custom-element"> 
  <template>
    <h1>I expect to be green</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-element',
      properties: {
        color: {
          type: String,
          value: 'red'
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.style.color = this.color;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I would expect that the following two would produce the same result:

1. (in markup)

   ```
   <body>
     <custom-element color="green"></custom-element>
   </body>
   ```
2. (in JS)

   ```
   var customElement = document.createElement('custom-element');
   customElement.color = 'green';
   document.body.appendChild(customElement);
   ```

But in fact it doesn't, as it seems that the properties are set and the polymer 'ready' function is triggered before the customElement is appended to document.body.

**So basically I cannot dynamically create (in JS) custom elements and set them initial properties, different than the default properties.**

How would you suggest I should do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `color` in `attached` callback instead of `ready`. `Attached` is called after the element has been appended in dom.

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="wecomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <h1>I expect to be green</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-element',
      properties: {
        color: {
          type: String,
          value: 'red'
        }
      },
      attached: function() {
        this.style.color = this.color;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var customElement = document.createElement('custom-element');
    customElement.color = 'green';
    document.body.appendChild(customElement);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Due to the circumstances of my particular project I am forced to do initialization in the ready() callback. I can show you why I need to do that, but the case is more complex than the initial question, which I adapted to simplify things.

Comment: In that case, you can set an interval in ready, which will basically hold ready till attachment is done.

Comment: I was able to move all the initialization in `attached`, so I will go with this as  the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would avoid altering the DOM and use a simple attribute binding.

Here is a proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/jozejemumu/1/edit?html,js,output

As you can see, I used attribute binding for the `style` attribute on the `h1` element, which simply sets the CSS color property to whatever the value of the elements' `color` property is.

The code is faily simple, and looks like this:

```
  <dom-module id="custom-element"> 
    <template>
      <h1 style$="color: [[color]];">I expect to be green</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'custom-element',
        properties: {
          color: {
            type: String,
            value: 'red'
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Using the element remains unchanged:

```
  <custom-element color="green"></custom-element>
```

Or:

```
  var customElement = document.createElement('custom-element');
  customElement.color = 'orange';
  document.body.appendChild(customElement);
```

Just make sure that the `color` property contains a valid HTML color name/value.